# Using Entity framework for the first time

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to learn and start using entity framework 5.0

I was able to create my data model (Only one table), but I am not able to find the commands / functions / methods that allow me to send sql queries and access the results and save and update...etc. Can someone write a very small block of code to show how to do so?

Comment: How did you create the model?

Comment: Right clicked on the project, add new item, chose ADO.net entity data model, and I selected the server / database / and tables needed.

Comment: you need to define a db context and instantiate it globally or in your class library

Comment: OK, then there should be a class that is derived from ObjectContext containing an `ObjectSet<YourClass>` that you can address with linq queries.

Comment: That class is called "SaleslogixSideProjectsEntities1". In my code I started with : 
            using (SaleslogixSideProjectsEntities1 DB = new SaleslogixSideProjectsEntities1())
            {
            } But Like I said, I am new to EF and Linq. I'd rather use native SQL, is there a way I can do so with EF? If not, can you include a sample of adding a record, getting a record and using its data in a text field, deleting a record and updating a record? If you can start with getting a record that would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer (use @username to "ping" someone). The whole point of EF is not to use handwritten SQL! You better study a good textbook, like one of Julie Lerman's books to get a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write raw SQL like so to return entities:

```
var entities = context.MyEntities.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyEntities").ToList();
```

Or for non entities:

```
var myAttributeValues = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
                      "SELECT MyAttribute FROM dbo.MyEntities").ToList();
```

However, you should not use raw sql just because you prefer it. You should use it in situations where raw sql provides you with an advantage over generated queries. If you prefer to write SQL then you should reconsider whether you really want to use EF or any other ORM at all. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) for some EF documentation and examples and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936) for info on querying for entities.